# :not selector is not working as expected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out for the life of me why my not selector isn't working. I've tried the `:not` and the `.not()` and for some reason the screen fades out onclick regardless of where you touch it, even when the restricted zone is specified in the not. I will post the code below.

HTML Code:

```
            <ul class="pages">
                <li class="login page">
                  <div class="form">
                    <input class="usernameInput" type="text" placeholder = "Reply to this chat (50 characters max)" maxlength="50" />
                  </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

JQuery Code:

```
      $(".pages:not(.form)").on('click', function(e){
        console.log("user clicked to exit");
        $(".pages").fadeOut(400); // remove reply box
        $('section, #main, #top, footer').show();
      });
```

I've also tried replace `.form` with `div` and `input` and it still hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.pages:not(.form)` selects an element that has the class `pages` and doesn't have the class `form` ... i.e your `ul` element

Comment: it selects all .page that are not from .form class at the same time.

Comment: @aatofighian - I think you'll find that its `.pages` not `.page`

Comment: the obvious question is, which element are you trying to add the event handler to?

Comment: Im trying to add the event listener to pages. However the user will still have to be able to click the reply input text box to type something. So I’m trying to do onclick of every item in pages except the form fadeOut

Comment: $( ".pages" ).not( ".form" ).on('click', function(e){......

Comment: @LDS I tried that already it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the input field visible while you click into it, or any element within the `.form` class, this function listens for any click within `.pages`.  If the element does not have a parent element with a `.form` class, then it hides the input.

```
$(".pages").on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    !$(e.target) // get the clicked element
      .parents() // look at it's parent elements
      .hasClass("form") // check if any of them have the form class and return the opposite with the !
  ) {
    $(".pages").fadeOut(400); // remove reply box if the parents don't contain the form class.
  }
  $("section, #main, #top, footer").show();
});
```

Comment: Ok, this is mostly correct. I removed the ```parents() ``` function and added the ```.show()``` in the if statement and that worked. Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
$('.pages:not(:has(.form))')
```

Comment: This keeps .pages on the screen even when clicked. I'm trying to keep the .pages on the screen only if form has been clicked. Any click outside should result in a fadeOut of the screen.

Comment: Well your question is about :not selector so that's what I answered.